# MAP interface using mobicents

Tags: java, dictionary, ss7, mobicents

Hi I'm tring to use jSS7 to build MAP interface to send message like this one :
https://code.google.com/p/jss7/source/browse/map/load/src/main/java/org/mobicents/protocols/ss7/map/load/Server.java
but I don't found any document or any demo to know how to change from USSD to SMS

Comment: I didn't found the way to change the USSD message to a simple message so unstand of sending USSD just send SMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no clear manul of how to implement different MAP messages because of there big count. Use MAP protocol specification (3GPP TS 29.002) to learn more.

You can check also opensource mobicent SMSC GW source code:
https://code.google.com/p/smscgateway/

Answer (score 3):

To tell the truth, I'm a bit unclear of what you would like to do.

USSDs and SMSes are really two different things, although there are similarities.

USSDs are intended for bidirectional communication between the user and network applications.

The VLR will invoke (on behalf of the user) `processUnstructuredSS-Request`
while the gsmSCF would invoke either `unstructuredSS-Request` or `unstructuredSS-Notify`:

- `processUnstructuredSS-Request`: Allows the user to send a request, getting back (optionally) a response)
- `unstructuredSS-Request`: Allows the application to present a prompt to the user, getting back a (optionally) response.
- `unstructuredSS-Notify`: Allows the application to present a message to the user, without response.

The key parameters in the different invoke and return result components are the

```
USSD-DataCodingScheme ::= OCTET STRING (SIZE (1))
-- The structure of the USSD-DataCodingScheme is defined by
-- the Cell Broadcast Data Coding Scheme as described in
-- TS 3GPP TS 23.038 [25]
USSD-String ::= OCTET STRING (SIZE (1..maxUSSD-StringLength))
-- The structure of the contents of the USSD-String is dependent
-- on the USSD-DataCodingScheme as described in TS 3GPP TS 23.038 [25].
```

More details in [3GPP TS 23.038](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/23038.htm)

---

Now, considering the SMS. In general two MAP operations are involved in the handling of SMS:
- MO-ForwardSM (sent to the VMSC) 
- MT-ForwardSM (sent to the GMSC)

In both cases the key parameters are:
- sm-RP-DA (the destination)
- sm-RP-OA (the origin)
- sm-RP-UI (the info)

The sm-RP-UI of type SignalInfo carries an SM-TL PDU (Short Message Transport Layer)
These are defined at [3GPP TS 23.040](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/23040.htm)

---

So, where's the connection?

The connection is that TP-Data-Encoding-Schema one of the components of a SM-TL PDU is the same as the USSD-DataCodingScheme in the USSD.

And that defines how both the TP-User-Data and the USSD-String are to be encoded.

Now you should really descend into all the gory details on the implementation and use of the USSD service and the SMS service to see how those are used in different scenarios.

Comment: JSantander, our company wants to implement an SMS router,  as per the 3GPP specifications. It seems that you have knowledge about the same. Are you open a project along those lines?

Comment: @sparkDabbler Thanks, but I'm not currently looking for a job.